# How to abort a C# console app after a set timeout

Tags: c#, flash, image-processing, console-application

We have an application that was developed by a 3rd party organization that in certain circumstances it will hang without exiting gracefully.

Here's the summary of the application:  It takes in a video, swf, image ...really any media and will capture a thumbnail at a specific frame or after a specified duration and output the thumbail to a specified directory.

I'm looking for a way to set a timeout on the function that captures the screen shots for the flash videos that will properly dispose the form, flash control and exit the app if the timeout has exceeded.   I could put a timer or stopwatch in the app and periodically check if the time specified had exceeded but that doesnt seem like a very eligant solution.  There has to be a better way.

Heres the function (its not very pretty):

```
    static void ThumbnailForSwf( String inputFile, String outputFile, Int32 w, Int32 h, float? time, float? quality ) {
        AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash flash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
        flash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point( 0, 0 );
        flash.ClientSize = new Size( w, h );
        flash.Enabled = true;
        flash.FSCommand += ( object sender, AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEvent e ) => {
            switch( e.command ) {
                case "trace":
                    Console.WriteLine( e.args );
                    break;
                case "error":
                    Console.WriteLine( e.args );
                    ( (Form)( (Control)sender ).Parent ).Close();
                    break;
                case "data":
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String( e.args );
                    using( FileStream fs = File.Open( outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write ) ) {
                        fs.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
                    }
                    break;
                case "done":
                    ( (Form)( (Control)sender ).Parent ).Close();
                    break;
            }
        };

        Form form = new Form();
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        form.Load += ( object sender, EventArgs e ) => {
            ( (Form)sender ).Visible = false;
            ( (Form)sender ).ClientSize = new Size( 0, 0 );
            try {
                flash.AllowNetworking = "all";
                flash.AllowScriptAccess = "always";
                flash.WMode = "window";
                flash.FlashVars = String.Format( "width={0}&height={1}&time={2}&quality={3}&input={4}", w, h, time ?? 0, quality ?? 80, inputFile );
                flash.Movie = Path.Combine( AssemblyDirectory, "FlashThumbnail.swf" );
            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                Console.WriteLine( ex.Message );
                ( (Form)sender ).Close();
            }
        };

        form.Controls.Add( flash );
        flash.CreateControl();
        Application.Run( form );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start this function as a Task and then you can monitor Task duration using like Stopwath and if Elapsed reaches some number just terminate that task